# How can you use an created object in another class?

Tags: java

For example...

**Startscreen Frame(Class):**

If i make an object in my startscreen frame: Player p1 = new Player("John");

**Game Frame(Class):**

How can i get access to this object in my game frame?

Comment: please give some codes .

Answer (score 3):

**How you can do it**

You can write a `getter`.

```
public Player getPlayer()
{
    return p1;
}
```

And make `p1` a field.

**What this might lead too**

If you're constantly making things like `p1` a field, then you're going to be left with an extremely messy class, very quickly.

**How to avoid this?**

If a class needs it only once, then pass it in at the constructor, and let the class do what it needs to do with it. Or you can put it into some sort of intermediate class.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of your startscreen frame in your game frame and get the `p1` object over this instance.

game class:

```
Startscreen startscreen = new Startscreen();
Player p1 = startscreen.getPlayer();
```

startscreen class:

```
private Player p1 = new Player("John");

public Player getPlayer() {
    return p1;
}
```